# If Checkbox is Checked Keep DIV hidden even on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I have a rails form. When a checkbox is selected (true in database) I want to keep the div hidden. I found other solutions but on page reload it reappears, I'd like to keep the div hidden if checked or true.

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.check_box :tos_checkbox, class: "terms_of_services" %>
    <%= form.label :tos_checkbox, "Agree to TOS" %>
  </div>

  <div id="hide_if_above_checked">
    Do You Agree to Our TOS
  </div>
```

I know this script will not work, but been attempting several different examples to solve my problem.

```
  $(function () {
      $('.terms_of_services').change(function () {
          if(checkbox.checked == true){
              document.getElementById("hide_if_above_checked").setAttribute("d-none");
          }else{
              document.getElementById("hide_if_above_checked").removeAttribute("d-none");
          }
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the checkbox value from db and check when rendering

```
 <%if @variable_of_current_model.tos_checkbox != 'true' %>
  <div id="hide_if_above_checked">
   Do You Agree to Our TOS
 </div>
<% end %>
```

the `div#hide_if_above_checked` will only be shown is the database is not true.

Comment: Awesome it worked. Appreciate it! I prefer this method too.

Answer (score 1):

To persist data you need to use either [`window.localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), [`window.sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) or [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

Cookies are even accessible by your backend

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of checkbox on page load.

```
if ($(".terms_of_services").is(':checked')){
  $("#some-div-box").hide();
}else{
  $("#some-div-box").show();
}
```

In that way if checkbox is checked then you can hide the div.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your CSS

```
.hidden-div {
  display: none;
}
```

and then

```
<div id="hide_if_above_checked" class="<%= 'hidden-div' if tos_checkbox %>">
  Do You Agree to Our TOS
</div>
```